# sencha touch 2 catalog application

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, catalog

m trying to develop a sencha touch 2 application that looks like a catalog, for example it depends on showing categories (restaurants, cinemas, shopping) it shows the categories as list, when tapping on any of the categories it immediately move to another list, showing the list of products for the category (example :list of restaurants). I have downloaded the source 
code of a sencha touch 2 application called the WatchList

http://www.watchlistapp.com/

but it doesn't satisfy what am looking for.

can anyone give me a tip for how to implement such catalog or a similar application source code that helps me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha Touch SDK come with `Touch Style` example which is essentially online e-commerce store, check out its code to get ideas. BTW if you want to see it in action here it is http://www.touchstyle.mobi/app/

Another easy app is https://github.com/kostysh/Simple-shopping-cart-for-Sencha-Touch-2 . Check out the demo link